# Helm can't find ECR protocol handler

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, amazon-ecr

While performing `helm repo add` I get the following error:

```
Error: could not find protocol handler for: ecr
```

I receive this error on different helm versions (3.8.0, 3.10.1, 3.12).

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [helm registries docs](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/registries/), it looks like helm latest versions natively supports OCI (the image specification AWS ECR uses), but you still need an ECR plugin in order for it to work.
The [plugin I found working](https://github.com/vetyy/helm-ecr) is `helm-ecr`:

```
helm plugin install https://github.com/vetyy/helm-ecr.git
```

Answer (score 0):

ECR is compatible with `helm` which includes the `helm CLI`, you do not need to have a helm plugin for ECR.
[OCI artifact support in Amazon ECR](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/oci-artifact-support-in-amazon-ecr/) goes over how to use ECR API to get a compatible helm registry login

Comment: This answer seems like it's just a link; can you expand this more to explain how to use the referenced API calls?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to create an OCI Image of a helm chart and use it in clusters, For all helm versions post 3.8.0, Here is a way to go about it,

**Create/Package OCI Image:**

In an existing helm repo, Ensure the chart name is written as expected in `Chart.yaml`, also ensure you're tracking the version of the app with `version` field of the file.

Package the chart with:
`$ helm package <chart-name>`

This'd create a file of name: `<chart-name>-<version>.tgz`, this is a valid OCI image which can be deployed on a cluster and is compatible with AWS ECR.
E.g. `nginx-0.1.6.tgz`

---

**Uploading the chart to AWS ECR:**

1. Create an ECR Repo with name same as: `<registry-name>/<chart-name>`
   E.g.

```
Suppose your Chart name is nginx-on-steroids and you want your registry to be called my-company-name (This is just a name, can be anything, keep it common for all charts of the org for similar setup of cluster)

The ECR Repo should be created with name : "my-company-name/nginx-on-steroids"
```

2. Login to ECR with:

`$ aws ecr get-login-password --region <region> | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin <aws_account_id>.dkr.ecr.<region>.amazonaws.com`

or

`$ aws ecr get-login-password --region <region> | helm registry login --username AWS --password-stdin <aws_account_id>.dkr.ecr.<region>.amazonaws.com`

both work fine as [both store the credentials in same location](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/registries/).

3. Now push the `.tgz` chart to registry with:
   `$ helm push <chart-name> <registry>`
   E.g. `$ helm push nginx-on-steroids my-company-name`

This will give output like:

```
Pushed: ***.dkr.ecr.<region>.amazonaws.com/my-company-name/nginx-on-steroids:0.1.6
Digest: sha256:c1bd780f358afcd1efd3d5144683b259fcf3e4424be1409735b04fed3f389fads
```

---

**Using the OCI Image in Cluster Directly:**

Login to ECR as described above, then you can perform following actions:

A. Pulling the image on local:

`$ helm pull oci://<aws_account_id>.dkr.ecr.<region>.amazonaws.com/my-company-name/nginx-on-steroids --version 0.1.6`

B. Deploy the chart in cluster:

`$ helm install my-new-release-nginx oci://<aws_account_id>.dkr.ecr.<region>.amazonaws.com/my-company-name/nginx-on-steroids --version 0.1.6`

---

**Using the OCI Image in Cluster as sub-chart:**

Login to ECR as described above, then in `Chart.yaml` of the chart where you want to use the OCI Image as sub chart, add dependencies of image like:

```
apiVersion: v2
name: mega-project
description: A super duper project
type: application
version: 0.1.0
appVersion: "0.1.0"
dependencies:
  - name: nginx-on-steroids
    repository: "oci://<aws_account_id>.dkr.ecr.<region>.amazonaws.com/my-company-name"
    version: "0.1.6"
```

*Notice*: Repository does not have the chart name only the Registry name.

In Values.yaml pass the values to sub-chart by creating a section with name of sub-chart like:

```
nameOverride: blah
...

nginx-on-steroids:
  serviceAccountName: something-else
  ...
```

---

Additional Docs:

Packaging Chart: https://helm.sh/blog/storing-charts-in-oci/

Dealing with registries: https://helm.sh/docs/topics/registries/

Pusing to ECR: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/push-oci-artifact.html